# Adding Iterator Variable to an Object Name

Tags: javascript

I have the following for loop:

```
for (var i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
     if (cookieJSON.Cases.mdata+i.toString() == undefined)
          return i;

}
```

I want the object name to equal `cookieJSON.Cases.mdata2` or `cookieJSON.Cases.mdata3` or `cookieJSON.Cases.mdata4` and so on.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets notation:

```
for (var i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
     if (cookieJSON.Cases["mdata" + i] == undefined)
          return i;
}
```

In JavaScript, you can access property names using either dot notation and a property name literal (`foo.bar`), or brackets notation and a property name *string** (`foo["bar"]`). The string can be the result of any expression, including string concatenation.

* In ES6, the thing in the brackets can also be a `Symbol`, but that's not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the key between brackets (`[]`) to form it from a string:

`cookieJSON.Cases['mdata' + i]`

Answer (score 0):

[Property Accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.

**Syntax**

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

E.g:-

```
for (var i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
      if (cookieJSON.Cases["mdata" + i] == undefined)
          return i;
}
```

More information here: [Dot Notation vs Brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)